# Who were before and afterwards, the mighty men or the sons of God? Genesis 6:4

Tags: hebrew, genesis, flood, nephilim

#### What I am not asking

I am not asking who the giants are, nor, who the sons of God are. Nor am I asking what the event was that marks the before and afterwards.

#### Question

In view of this passage

> “There were giants on the earth in those days, and also afterward, when the sons of God came in to the daughters of men and they bore children to them. Those were the mighty men who were of old, men of renown.”
> ‭‭Genesis‬ ‭6:4‬ ‭

Specifically surrounding the phrase “and also afterwards” וגם אחרי כן

Whatever the ‘afterwards’ is

Based on the Hebrew text grammar, who or what was before and also afterwards?

1. Giants were before and afterwards
2. sons of God laying with the daughters of men and having offspring were before and afterwards

Which of these is it, or is it another explanation from within the immediate passage or broader context?

Comment: What version are you quoting ? Both the KJV and YLT punctuate differently and cast a different meaning altogether from what you are quoting.

Comment: I wish not to dwell on translations, it is the Hebrew that I am most interested in. I can’t quite see how a translation, a second hand document can relay with *greater* accuracy that which the original intended to convey. For if I were going to select a translation I would be tempted humanly speaking to choose according to my own prejudice and bias. And that would defeat the purpose of seeking truth, a non starter. But I do believe it was the NKJV that I quoted to answer your question @NigelJ

Comment: The NKJV is not grammatical in this verse. 'When etc' is a clause. There is no verb to tell us what happened ... when. The verse in this version does not make sense. It isn't proper English.

Comment: Once again @NigelJ English translations or any other translation is not of concern to me, the original, does it point to the giants הנפלים or the sons of God בני האלהים ?

Comment: And to the person who voted to close this question for lack of understanding the question, though I was trying not to influence the answer and attempted to leave the question ambiguous purposefully, in plain English the question is, **who were before and also after the flood according to Genesis 6:4, the giants or the sons of God?**

Comment: @NihilSineDeo—This question is certainly on topic and the propensity of some to immediately VTC without at least requesting further clarification from the original poster is only hurting this Stack Exchange site. Do better. If not, this site will die.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo That is exactly the point : 'the sons ... daughters ... bore children ... mighty men' are all part of one grammatical construction occurring 'afterward' which the translations of the KJV and YLT make abundantly clear.

Comment: Ok that’s a new idea @NigelJ, you are saying that all three groups were afterwards. And it’s at this point that I would like a second opinion on the Hebrew rather than continue to discuss a translation because I never understood this from the English before. I could quote this text in other languages and the translation makes it very clear it was only the giants that were before and afterwards.

Comment: I honestly don't understand where you see the word *before* in the text. As for *afterward*, I deem it rather obvious that (the birth of) the *giants* or *mighty men* took place **after** the *sons of God* mated with the *daughters of men*.

Comment: It’s not before it’s in those days בימים ההם and also afterwards וגם אחרי כן
which is the same as saying before and afterwards @Lucian

Comment: @NihilSineDeo: As far as I can tell from context (Genesis 6:1-4), the two expressions (*those days* and *when the sons of God entered to the daughters of men*) seem to be synonymous, referring to one and the same time frame. Since the latter event gave birth to the so-called *giants* or *mighty men of old*, they too seem to have been contemporaries of these events, with the small caveat that one action (begetting) logically precedes the other (the offspring's existence), hence *afterwards*.

Comment: @Lucian it appears you skipped the first part of the proposition. Maybe you could write a response such that I can understand why you ignored the portion about “giants being on the earth in those days and also afterwards.” ... It doesn’t seem that the text would read “giants were on the earth. In those days and also afterward when the sons of God and the daughters of men copulated and had giants”. Also the implication is that in those days and also afterwards (time of Moses) the sons of God copulated with the daughters of men giving birth to giants (NigelJ’s interpretation).

Comment: @NihilSineDeo: *There were giants in those days, after the sons of God came in to the daughters of men and they bore children to them*.

Comment: I understand that’s how you are reading it @Lucian which is why I’m asking for a breakdown of the Hebrew. Further the Nephilim appear to be the Gibborim. I appreciate you sharing your understanding in the English but I’ll await for a second opinion in the Hebrew. Thank you.

Comment: @NihilSineDeo: (1). I am Romanian, and I understand several foreign languages other than English. (2). Feel free to create an account on Judaism.SE.

Comment: @Lucian which Romanian translation do you use? I happen to know some Romanian by no means a master, I took it in high school for several years together with Italian

Comment: @NihilSineDeo: The Protestant *Cornilescu* version reads similarly to the English. The Orthodox version reads more like what I am suggesting, as do the German Lutheran and English Douay-Rheims Bibles.

Comment: Actually it doesn’t, neither of the two translations do. În vremea aceea s-au ivit pe pământ uriași, mai cu seamă de când fiii lui Dumnezeu începuseră a intra la fiicele oamenilor și acestea începuseră a le naște fii: aceștia sunt vestiții viteji din vechime. Clearly the subject are the giants and they came about by way of the copulation of the SofG with the DofM. They the giants existed before and afterwards. The Cornilescu 1924 edition is more ambiguous due to old Romanian but the revised edition explicitly states it’s the giants that were before and after. @Lucian

Comment: Even the DRC Bible because of the word FOR still makes the giants the subject of the verse before and afterwards. You can choose to not read it into the text but it wouldn’t make sense what it is trying to say then “Now giants were upon the earth in those days. For after the sons of God went in to the daughters of men, and they brought forth children, these are the mighty men of old, men of renown.”
‭‭Genesis‬ ‭6:4‬ ‭

Answer (score 1):

Current mainstream Christian and Rabbinical traditions choose option 1 instead of option 2.

Thus there were giants in those days (before the flood) and also afterwards (after the flood). The giants after the flood were descended from the giants before the flood (a slight point in favor of the flood not being global). Goliath and his odd kinsmen were examples of such giants, and it was reported by the spies that there were giants in Palestine, as per Numbers 13.33:

> There we saw the giants (the descendants of Anak came from the
> giants); and we were like grasshoppers in our own sight, and so we
> were in their sight.” [NKJV]

However, some rabbinical traditions at the time of Christ that were popular in Palestine choose option 2. Option 2 does not speak to the universality of the flood at all, as it would allow for more such offspring even after the flood. That is, many believed there were *still* libidinous angels that would seek out virgins to sleep with or at least violate somehow. We also see this in Paul's writings:

1 Cor 11.10:

> Because of this, the woman ought to have a symbol of authority on her
> head, **on account of the angels**. [LEB]

The interpretation of the phrase  *because of the angels*  will determine whether option 1 or option 2 is believed at the time of Paul's writings.

One possibility of the head covering was to ward off these angels. Here is the (excellent) Hermeneia commentary discussing interpretations of this passage[1]:

> What is the meaning of διὰ τοὺς ἀγγέους, “because of the angels”?
> Several suggestions are made. **The fallen angels of Gen 6:1f. are
> meant. The demons are held to be sexually libidinous.** Yet the
> thought need not be that of their sexual desire in particular. **It can
> also be a general allusion to the possibility of woman in her weakness
> being harmed by demons**. Others think of the order of creation,
> arguing that the angels are the protectors of this order. But
> Lietzmann rightly objects that in that case ἐξουσία would have to be
> understood as a sign of subordination, which does not suit the word at
> all. Finally, there are those who think of the presence of angels at
> divine worship. If the statement is understood in its context as
> giving a reason (διὰ τοῦτο, “for this reason,” and διὰ τοὺς ἀγγέλους,
> “because of the angels”), then the ἐξουσία is a protection, in the
> sense of a compensation for the natural weakness of woman (in
> metaphysical terms: because she is God’s image only in a derivative
> sense) over against cosmic power. Paul has no interest in further,
> more precise definitions.

This connection was also argued by Tertullian[2]:

> **Of course, it is on account of the angels, he says, that the woman’s
> head is to be covered, because the angels revolted from God on account
> of the daughters of men**. Who, then, would contend that it is only
> women, that is, married women no longer virgins, that are a source of
> temptation? Unless, of course, unmarried women may not present an
> attractive appearance and find their lovers? Rather, let us see
> whether it was virgins alone whom they desired when Scripture speaks
> of the ‘daughters of men’; for it could have used the terms ‘men’s
> wives’ or ‘women’ indifferently. But, since it says: ‘And they
> took to themselves wives,’ it does so because they took as their wives
> those without husbands. Scripture would have used a different
> expression for those who had husbands. Now, they could be without
> husbands either because they were widows or virgins. So, in naming the
> sex in general by the term ‘daughters,’ he embraced species in genus.

Thus this interpretation would support option 2. One can also view this prophetically, e.g. that the bride (the church) is subject to being defiled (committing fornication or adultery) by evil spirits when she is not under authority, and the offspring of such a union is a grotesque monster, a mixing of the church with the world.

However others argue that "because of the angels" in Paul's writing is to be taken that we have guardian angels that protect us, contrasting Gen 6.4, so even though this passage is viewed as a reference to Gen 6.4, the meaning is reversed. For example, St. John Chrysostom [3]:

> Hence it is evident, that the saints have angels, or even all men. For
> the apostle too saith of the woman, “That she ought to have power on
> her head because of the angels.” And Moses, “He set the bounds of the
> nations according to the number of the angels2 of God.” But here He is
> discoursing not of angels only, but rather of angels that are greater
> than others. But when He saith, “The face of my Father,” He means
> nothing else than their fuller confidence, and their great honor.

And this became the more widely accepted tradition in modern Christianity, which would support option 1 rather than option 2.

---

[1] Conzelmann, H. (1975). 1 Corinthians: a commentary on the First Epistle to the Corinthians (pp. 189–190). Philadelphia: Fortress Press.

[2] Tertullian. (1959). Disciplinary, Moral, and Ascetical Works. (H. Dressler, Ed., R. Arbesmann, E. J. Daly, & E. A. Quain, Trans.) (Vol. 40, pp. 178–179). Washington, DC: The Catholic University of America Press.

[3] John Chrysostom. (1888). Homilies of St. John Chrysostom, Archbishop of Constantinople on the Gospel according to St. Matthew. In P. Schaff (Ed.), G. Prevost & M. B. Riddle (Trans.), Saint Chrysostom: Homilies on the Gospel of Saint Matthew (Vol. 10, p. 368). New York: Christian Literature Company.

Comment: The means that they cross the world wide flood does not demand a local flood. They crossed by way of Noah’s daughter in laws Canaan his first grandchild being a carrier of Nephilim genes. Back to rereading your answer

Comment: Interesting points.

Comment: Yes, that's possible, @NihilSineDeo, but I only said "a point in favor", not "conclusive proof", and then updated to "slight point", since I don't want to get into a debate about the flood's extent (I don't have a strong opinion there)

Answer (score 0):

I will clarify. The sages teach that these Nephilim were angels who despised the humans for their sins and G-d told them that they wouldn't be able to stand up to the trial of not sinning, moreover that they will sin harder. Therefore they are called Nephilim - 'The fallen', and B'nei Ha'elokim - The sons of the mighty - which signifies both that they were with the almighty, and that they themselves were phisically huge.

Thus the event was before the flood when the humans sinned grieviously and the angels despised them etc.

Comment: That’s not what the sages taught but if you can include a reference I might consider your interpretation. The fallen angels and human women had children those are the Nephilim. Nimrod became a Nephilim and he wasn’t an ‘angel’

Comment: Nimrod is definitly not from the Nefilim. And the sages, Jewish, say that explicitly in the Midrash rabah and, if I remember correctly, quoted by Rashi on the spot.

Comment: He was a Gibborim which in the Samaritan text both Gibborim and Nephilim are one and the same.

Comment: Not the same at all. Compare גיבורים נפילים in dictionary. Also study the story of Nimrod, he called to actively mutiny against G-d, he condemned Avraham to the fire, and he was the head king in the 4-5 kings war (Amrophel אמרפל). According to the Jewish original text.

Comment: Once again show me a reference that the Nephilim were the Benei Ha’Elohim and we can talk after. Until then the Nephilim are their children from the sons of God’s copulation with human women.

Comment: אחר המבול. והנה בני ענק בתחילה היו ממשפחת בני האלהים: quote from the Ibn Ezra. and if you really want to know the meaning of the bible, learn Jewish beacause it was given and explained to us. sof pasuk!

Comment: see https://he.wikisource.org/wiki/%D7%9E%22%D7%92_%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%90%D7%A9%D7%99%D7%AA_%D7%95_%D7%93

Comment: I’m going to go with you can’t read Hebrew properly because it says the fallen were in the land in those days and also afterwards when the sons of God came to the daughters of men and they bore children to them. In other words the sons of God and the fallen are different, whereas my understanding from your response (correct me if I’m wrong) you’re saying the fallen were sons of God. Also the sons of the giants were from the family of the sons of God. Once again they are not the same.

Comment: There was something called megafauna also. Gigantic animals, that is. Proven by archeological diggings.